# Append Reporter.log with Log.info

Tags: eclipse, search, replace

Any one know how to replace a line with two lines in eclipse?

Example:

Find:
`Log.info("variable 1");`

Replace:
`Log.info("variable 1");`
`Reporter.log("variable 1");`

Note:
1. I have more than 3000 line of Log.info to replace
2. The "variable 1" is different for all the logs.